# How to add multiple types of references in a LaTeX document

Tags: citing, natbib

I would like to have a reference with:

```
... as further discussed by Author (year).
```

And additionally another reference as:

```
... in the Middle East the average size of a family is X (author, year).
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tagged this question with `natbib`, have you taken a look at its [package documentation](http://mirror.kku.ac.th/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natbib.pdf)? The [reference sheet](http://mirror.kku.ac.th/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/natbib/natnotes.pdf) is useful as a quick/short introduction, if you are new to this, I think.

I show a small example below, using `\citet` for Author(Year) and `\citep` for (Author,Year):

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{feyn54,
    author = {R. P. Feynman},
    journal = {Phys. Rev.},
    year = {1954},
    volume = {94},
    pages = {262}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}

\begin{document}
    \texttt{author (year)} using \verb!\citet!: \ldots As further discussed by~\citet{feyn54}

    \texttt{(author,year)} using \verb!\citep!: \ldots size of a family is X\citep{feyn54}

    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    \bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image: small eg]

Comment: This seems exactly what I need! Thanks a whole bunch.